# REPLACE doesn't work for strings in BigQuery

Tags: string, replace, google-bigquery

I tried to use `REPLACE` to delete some words, like 'HOMEMAKER' and 'HOUSEWIFE', from strings. But I failed to change those words into empty space. Why is that happening?

I want to delete strings like '*HOMEMAKER*' and '*HOUSEWIFE*' from column EMPLOYER using `REPLACE` function but failed. I also tried REGEXP_REPLACE but failed again. These are the table I have (Sorry I want to build a table here but somehow it doesn't work).

> EMPLOYER
>     RETIRED/HOMEMAKER
>     HOMEMAKER/HOMEMAKER
>     SELF-EMPLOYED/HOMEMAKER

We code is listed below:

```
SELECT EMPLOYER,
       CASE WHEN EMPLOYER LIKE '%HOUSE%WIFE%'
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(EMPLOYER,r'HOUSE%WIFE',' ')
            WHEN EMPLOYER LIKE '%HOME%MAKER%'
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(EMPLOYER, r'HOME%MAKER', ' ')
            ELSE '0'
            END AS SIGN
FROM fec.work
WHERE EMPLOYER LIKE '%HOME%MAKER%' 
OR EMPLOYER LIKE '%HOUSE%WIFE%'
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The result I want is like:

> SIGN
>   RETIRED/
>   /
>   SELF-EMPLOYED/

But I got exactly the same columns in `SIGN` as `EMPLOYER`. Can anyone tell me why `replace` function did not make any changes?

Comment: what do you mean by `with empty space`? can you provide example of such entry and what is desired result. meantime - while `%` applicable with `LIKE` it has no same use in `REGEXP_REPLACE` and is treated just as single character `%` - thus no replacement happens

Comment: @Min Sun you say you failed but you don't actually say what happened. Could you an example of a result you're getting along with what you would like it to be?

Comment: Apologize. It's my first time ask questions here. I edit my question. Hope this time I explained it clearly. I want to delete words like 'HOMEMAKER' in 'EMPLOYER' column.

Comment: @ Calum Halpin The result I got is that column `SIGN` and column 'EMPLOYER' are exactly the same. `REPLACE` did no changes to the column.

Comment: While it's been pointed out that `%` is NOT a wildcard in regular expressions, nobody has pointed out what IS. You can mimic the same behavior with `.*` (`.` = match any character; `*` = zero or more times). If you want specific characters, you can use something like this: `[ -]*` (match space or dash zero or more times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these options should work for your case.

```
with test as (
  select 'EMPLOYER' as my_str             union all 
  select 'RETIRED/HOMEMAKER' as my_str    union all 
  select 'HOMEMAKER/HOMEMAKER' as my_str  union all 
  select 'SELF-EMPLOYED/HOMEMAKER' as my_str
)
select 
  my_str,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(my_str, 'HOUSEWIFE', ' '), 'HOMEMAKER', ' ') as replaced_str,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(my_str, r'HOUSEWIFE|HOMEMAKER', ' ') as regexed_str
from test
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like below

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(EMPLOYER, r'HOUSEWIFE|HOMEMAKER',' ')
```

you can use `i` flag to make this replacement case insensitive

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(EMPLOYER, r'(?i)HOUSEWIFE|HOMEMAKER',' ')
```

Comment: I would add that OP's original question was matching characters (likely meant to be a dash/space) in the string, so I'd say it would be correct to use the pattern `r'(?i)HOUSE[ -]*WIFE|HOME[ -]*MAKER'` or at least the exact analogue of OP's code with `r'(?i)HOUSE.*WIFE|HOME.*MAKER'`. (Since most folks aren't fluent with regular expressions, I find it helps to match their use case as closely as possible so they don't have to figure out how to modify them.)

Comment: @justbeez - it is hard to read OP's mind - but per his question he ` want to delete strings like 'HOMEMAKER' and 'HOUSEWIFE' from column EMPLOYER`. obviously you can then adjust it to whatever really needed :o)

Comment: Fair point about mind-reading, but I can read his code (`REGEXP_REPLACE(EMPLOYER,r'HOUSE%WIFE',' ')`)—clearly an intent to replace a string with optional characters in the middle. Not a criticism of you in any way (the quality of your contributions on this tag are top-notch), just trying to add value for OP without over-editing an answer to say something significantly different (which in hindsight, an edit was probably the better option). Cheers!

Comment: from your comments - `Since most folks aren't fluent with regular expressions` - so I do not trust code in such cases and prefer rely on verbal expression of use-case. But you are free to add your answer if you want - the more the merrier :o)